# Algebraic Curves - Resultant. Application to polynomial systems

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Problem:** Consider the following polynomials on $\mathbb C^2$: \begin{align*}
>  f_1(x,y)&=x^3-2yx^2+(1+2y)x+1+y^3\\
>     f_2(x,y)&=x^3+x^2+(1+y+y^2)x+1+y+y^3 \end{align*} Get all the solutions of the system $f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)=0$.

The resultants $R_1(x)=\mathcal R(f_1,f_2,y)$ y $R_2(y)=\mathcal R(f_1,f_2,x)$ are given by:
\begin{align*}
    R_1(x)&=-3x^9+8x^8-7x^7+7x^6+x^5-4x^4+7x^3-6x^2+2x-1\\
    R_2(y)&=3y^9+13y^8+21y^7+40y^6+54y^5+48y^4+44y^3+24y^2+8y+1
\end{align*}

It is well know that: *Given $x_0\in\mathbb C$, there exists $y_0\in\mathbb C$ such that $f_1(x_0,y_0),f_2(x_0,y_0)=0$ if and only if $R_1(x_0)=0$*. Thus, we are interested in obtaining the solutions of $R_1(x)=0$ and $R_2(x)=0$. The roots of $R_1(x)$ are (approximately):
\begin{align*}
    x_1&=0.49468322334953i+0.07611305001234\\
    x_2&=0.07611305001234-0.49468322334953i\\
    x_3&=-0.96296685313133\\
    x_4&=0.9426064764521i-0.11537717327113\\
    x_5&=-0.9426064764521i-
0.11537717327113\\
x_5&=0.75907158005558\\
x_6&=0.88395558541354i+0.43032655349256\\
x_7&=0.43032655349256-0.88395558541354i\\
x_8&=2.088437079274874
\end{align*}
and $R_2(y)$:
\begin{align*}
    y_1&=-0.22960599244208\\
    y_2&=0.34317617844637i-0.31207753044374\\
    y_3&=-0.34317617844637i-0.31207753044374\\
    y_4&=1.0305547776518i+0.061234407815197\\
    y_5&=0.061234407815197-1.0305547776518i\\
    y_6&=1.305704128259301i+0.27563822200361\\
    y_7&=0.27563822200361-1.305704128259301i\\
    y_8&=-1.206270563706464\\
    y_9&=-2.947046975934931
\end{align*}
It is clear that there exists a multiple root of $R_1(x)=0$. How can I get the pairs $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f_1(x_0,y_0)=f_2(x_0,y_0)=0$?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you use the Groebner method?

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/):  `R=QQ[x,y,MonomialOrder=>Lex]` `I=ideal(x^3-2*y*x^2+2*x*y+x+1+y^3,x^3+x^2+(1+y+y^2)*x+1+y+y^3)` `gens gb I` yields $3y^9+13y^8+21y^7+40y^6+54y^5+48y^4+44y^3+24y^2+8y+1, 6808x+11373y^8+43952y^7+58691y^6+121491y^5+139965y^4+105485y^3+105025y^2+30033y+8873$. The nine roots in $y$ of the first give each a $x$ in the other.